# What is the correct regex to match uppercase letter for only first letter in words

Tags: java, regex

Now my program use this pattern `.*[A-Z].*` to match every word that has an uppercase letter. But my problem is, I need a pattern that can identify a word with an uppercase only on the beginning of word.

Example Input for my program now:-

My name is Johan and I am from langKawi.

Output Matched:
My Johan I langKawi.

But using my pattern a word like langKawi where the uppercase is not at the beginning of a word it still matched.

Can anyone help me with the pattern where it match a word that has uppercase for the first letter only and my text/input only consist alphabetical characters without number and symbols.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Use a word boundary to match just before a word starts, then the word, then another word boundary:

```
\b[A-Z]\w*\b
```

That, in Java, looks like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b([A-Z]\\w*)\\b");

String s = "My name is Johan and I am from langKawi.";
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(s);

while(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

This outputs:

```
My
Johan
I
```

Comment: @zx81: otherwise the regex will include (potential) word bounds like spaces. In order to prevent this, you group only the imporant part.

Comment: @CommuSoft Not so: the `\b` is a zero-width assertion. It doesn't consume. :)

Comment: @zx81: out of curiosity: what if you want to capture the boundary (say you are interested in the delimiter at the end of the word).

Comment: Capturing the boundary is a common and useful technique. It's used for instance for splitting in "invisible places", as between the camel-space separators in `myBeautifulCamel` I am talking about boundaries in the broadest sense, including `\b` and DIY boundaries such as lookarounds.

Comment: I have tested the pattern with my data and it works. Thank you very much nick.

Answer (score 2):

That's why they invented `\b`:

```
\b[A-Z][A-Za-z]*\b
```

[`\b`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html) acts as a word boundary: it matches spaces (and other delimiters) or the begin and end of a string.

Example to capture all parts:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b([A-Z][a-z]*)\\b");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("My name is Johan and I am from langKawi.");
        while(m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
     }
}
```

You can test the code [here](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php).

Comment: Thank you very much @CommuSoft. I should learn on how to use \b more and learn about its function.